# Calling a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, dom-events

I'm a beginner in React, and I'm a little confused about calling a function in React.

I saw the following ways and I don't know when to use each and which one.

- `handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo}`
- `handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo()}`
- `handleAddTodo ={handleAddTodo}`
- `handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo}`
- `handleAddTodo ={handleAddTodo()}`

Are these interchangeable? Could I do that to handle an event, the same way to call a function?

Comment: do you want to trigger an event from other component?

Comment: Are you sure you want to call a function not to pass it as a property of child component?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko : yeah i pass a function calling, this is a prop of a child, isn't passing a function implicitly considered as calling for it ?

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare "isn't passing a function implicitly considered as calling for it" no. You either pass a function (so that your child component could call it some time later aka "callback") or you call it and pass the result it returns.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Are these interchangeable?

Short answer: No.

---

Let's take a look at the different snippets you've posted:

#### `someFunction()` vs `someFunction`

With the former syntax, you are actually invoking that function. The latter is just a reference to that function. So when do we use which?

- You would use `someFunction()` when you want that function invoked and its result returned immediately. In React, this is typically seen when you split parts of your JSX code to a separate function; either for reasons of readability or reusability. For example:

  ```
  render() {
    myFunction() {
      return <p>Foo Bar</p>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {myFunction()}
      </div>
    );
  }
  ```

---

- You would use `someFunction` when you want only to pass the reference to that function to something else. In React, this is usually an event handler that is passed down to another child-component via `props` so that that component can call the event handler when it needs to. For example:

  ```
  class myApp extends React.Component {
    doSomething() {
      console.log("button clicked!");
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Button someFunction={this.doSomething} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.props.someFunction}>Click me</button>
      );
    }
  }
  ```

---

#### `someFunction()` vs `this.someFunction()`

This has to do with the context of the function. Basically, "where is this function?". Is part of the current Component, then use `this.someFunction()`, is it part of the parent Component passed in as props, then use `this.props.someFunction()`. Is it a function inside the current method, then just use `someFunction()`.

Obviously, there's a lot more to it than that, but it's the best basic summary I can give.

For a better understanding, have a read [**here**](https://gist.github.com/amitai10/adb66d6faa714e8c3cdb94946bb98356). It is a great guide to how the `this` keyword works in Javascript and in React in particular.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to **call** a function options 2 and with some assumptions 5 should work.

If you want to actually **pass** a function as a property to some child component so that it could call it later (say to notify your root element on some event) then option 1 (with prebind) and 3 (with defining a variable `const  {handleAddTodo} = this` and prebind :) ) should work

```
// this works if handleAddTodo was prebinded or doesn't use this
handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo} 

// this probably wont work unless handleAddTodo is higher order function that returns another function
handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo()} 

// This wont work unless you have a var/let/const that is referencing a function
handleAddTodo ={handleAddTodo} 

// Same as 1
handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo} 

// 3 and 2 combined
handleAddTodo ={handleAddTodo()}
```

Answer (score 3):

To call the **function** you have to add ()

```
{this.handleAddTodo()}
```

About handling events - [Handling#Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

Arrow Functions - [Functions#ArrowFunctions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 you can use normal function or Arrow Function:

***Function1 (Normal Function)***

```
functionA(){
   //Something here
}
```

Then should call ***this.functionA()***

***Function2 (ArrowFunction)***

```
functionA = () => {
   //SomeThing Here
}
```

Then should call ***this.functionA***

***Function3 (Eg: in a const of React)  ***

```
const A = (functionTest) =>{
  return (
     <div>{functionTest}</div>
    );
}
```

***functionTest*** is mapStateToProps in React :)

I hope it is helpful for you :)

Answer (score 2):

this is correct -> `handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo}`
When function passing to child component you have to bind your function  like this `handleAddTodo ={this.handleAddTodo.bind(this)}`. below code help out your doubt.

**Simple Example**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: 'Initial data...'
      }

      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);

   };

   updateState() {
      this.setState({data: 'Data updated...'})
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick = {this.updateState}>CLICK</button>
            <h4>{this.state.data}</h4>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

**Child Events**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: 'Initial data...'
      }

      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
   };

   updateState() {
      this.setState({data: 'Data updated from the child component...'})
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Content myDataProp = {this.state.data} 
               updateStateProp = {this.updateState}></Content>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Content extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick = {this.props.updateStateProp.bind(this)}>CLICK</button>
            <h3>{this.props.myDataProp}</h3>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

[Refer here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_events.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger events with `this.props.someProps()`. Check the following sample.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    

class AddToDo extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <button onClick={ev => this.props.handleAddToDo(ev, 'hello')}>
            {this.props.title}
         </button>
      )
   }
}

class Todos extends Component {
   handleAddToDo(ev, someVal) {
      // do something
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <AddToDo title="Add" handleAddToDo={(ev, someVal) => this.handleAddToDo(ev, someVal)} />
      )
   }
}

export default Todos;
```